problems with LyX and TeXlive shell after updating to LyX 2.4
Ever since I updated LyX I've had 3 problems:

whenever I open an older file (which was created before LyX 2.4) I get the following pop-up, and I don't know how to stop it from happening, those files have no changes at all.


the preview environment doesn't work for any of my older files, even if I create a new one there, so it only works for files created after LyX 2.4, (the file compiles and everything it's just inside the LyX document that the preview has no effect.

I'm not sure if its related but my TeXlive shell doesn't seem to allow me to install any packages, I must admit I know next to nothing when it comes to this program, I just followed a guide blindly, you can see in the image that even though I marked the package "bigfoot" it doesn't let me install it.



(I'll add that I've followed a guide so that I can write in Hebrew so I have many packages that are related to that and I don't fully know what packages are there)

the last one says "TL manager up to date? Needs updating". That means you must click first on the "update tlmgr" button.

@UlrikeFischer alright thank you! solved problem #3 then.
